# Symfony - Random generator for the CSRF-token creates error

Tags: php, csrf, symfony

We are running a Syfmonfy 3.1.2 site on a server which has PHP 5.5.9 installed. Everything works fine, except that we have to deal with a problem creating the CSRF-token:

> There is no suitable CSPRNG installed on your system

This is [related](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/issues/99) to the [Random Compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) bundle. It seems that `/dev/urandom` is not available.

---

We still want to secure our forms with a CSRF-token and they even [provide a fallback](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/releases/tag/v1.3.0):

```
try {
    $bytes = random_bytes(32);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $strong = false;
    $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32, $strong);
    if (!$strong) {
        throw $ex;
    }
}
```

Now, how can I implement this? I don't want to tweak the Symfony core nor the bundle to not get into trouble with every future update. I simply have no idea where to hook it up.

Answer (score 0):

As shown [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/csrf_in_login_form.html#configuring-csrf-protection), you have to give a token generator when configuring CSRF protection:

```
# app/config/security.yml

security:
    # ...
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            # ...
            form_login:
                # ...
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager # <-here
```

Instead of the default `security.csrf.token_manager` service, give your own token manager.

Your custom tokenManager must implements `CsrfTokenManagerInterface`:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
```

Declare it as a service, and then you should be done

**Update after comment**

To provide the token_manager to your other forms you can try to specify it in the form options:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        // csrf options
        'csrf_protection'    => true,
        'csrf_field_name'    => '_token',
        'csrf_token_id'      => 'task_item',
        'csrf_token_manager' => 'YourBundle\Path\To\YourCustomCsrfTokenManager'
        // other ones...
    ));
}
```

I didn't find anything in the documentation, but looking at Symfony's source code I found the `csrf_token_manager` option [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Csrf/Type/FormTypeCsrfExtension.php#L88), it should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I also thought that I could write my own token generator in this case. The example you have shown, explains how to add a token generator to the login form. But how do I provide a token generator for all other forms? I can't find any place in the config files.